# How I can retrieve data from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables in my  database.

table1:

[image]

table2:

[image]

How I can write sql query retrieve all the data from table1 by id=201102887 which is written in table2

Comment: these are MySQL tables right...?

Comment: yes,they are. I made it in phpmyadmin

Comment: OK and by what attribute are the tables related?

Comment: no relation between the tables

Comment: I see; the query SELECT id, major FROM table1 WHERE id = 201102887 will get the record from table1 but without a relationship matching this id to any of the records in table2 you'll struggle to get anything useful. You might want to add another table that maps ids in table1 to records in table2 and that will allow you to perform a JOIN statement on all 3 tables...

Comment: try to avoid posting links to images and instead add your table structure  in your question, along with a sample of your actual data and the results you want.

Comment: @FarhanAlShammery, if your tables don't have a relation, or, in other words, _are unrelated_, how do you know (or _how is MySQL supposed to know_) which rows belong together? Please learn the basics of relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `JOIN` will do.

```
select table1.*
from table1 inner join table2 ON table1.title = table2.major
where table2.id = 201102887
```

Comment: Now I change it but show my  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).